# How to access the contents of a link path that cannot be accessed 403 Error

Tags: http, web, search, directory

There are links on the Internet, where direct access to the site directory is not possible. But Google can see those paths and display files that are in that direction.
Is there any way to show a list of links in that link path?

ex.

- **http_://site.com/files/paper.pdf**
  -

> Blockquote

...
when typed address bar go to

> http_://site.com/pic/ ***//show Error 403 Forbidden Access***

but when search on Google

> filetype:pdf site:htt*p://site.co*m/files/

result is :
htt*p://_site.co*m/files/paper.pdf

I want See all files that exist in path same as Google Search Engine ?

**note**:i want see for another person website not myself web..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google can only do what a user does. If directory listing is forbidden, it is the same for Google. The only exception is when there is a rule based on the request headers. Generally the user agent value. You can change your user agent header in order to pretend you are Google. Here are the [values they use](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl%3Den).

But to be honest I think what happens in your case is that the file is just referenced somewhere in the site. What Google does is go through a process called "Crawling" which more or less means that a script starts at the homepage, searches all the links and filepaths on this page, and then follow all the links until it has everything. If you did the same (there are softwares and apps for this) you'd most likely find that this file was used or referenced somewhere on a page of the website.

Not allowing directory listing is a common setting on most web servers. You can access the files if the path is knows, but you cannot inspect it. It prevents people from discovering files you don't want them to know yet, or not at all. It is not strong enough to be a security feature though.